# Fundamental Group of the Space X

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

May I know what is the name of this space $X$ obtained from the picture above?

Also, what is its fundamental group? I tried calculating by triangulation and using a algorithm involving maximal trees, and obtained $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, not sure if it is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless there is a 2-cell inside. Then it is a 3-fold dunce cap with fundamental group $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @AlexS Good call. Thinking about it, the denominations on the lines and the vertices seem to heavily endorse your interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is a little ambiguous. If this just a triangle with nothing inside, then it is topologically the same as a circle wrapped around itslef three times, which is still a circle. As we know, a circle has fundamental group $\mathbb Z$.

If there is stuff inside the triangle (i.e., the triangle has a two cell attached to it), this is a space often called a [dunce cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)). Specifically, because there are three segments identified, it is a 3-fold dunce cap. Its fundamental group is given by $$\pi_1(X)=\langle a|a^3\rangle=\mathbb Z_3.$$

Comment: Thanks so much. When triangulating the dunce cap, how is it different from triangulating the empty triangle with nothing inside?

Comment: @yoyostein Loosely speaking, they are different because any closed path on the dunce cap has more ways to deform than a closed path on a circle. So there are more homotopies which make non-homotopic paths on the circle homotopic on the dunce cap.

Comment: Could you briefly describe how to triangulate the dunce cap? Thanks! (I tried triangulating but got the "circle wrapped around 3 times" instead)

Comment: Note that the object in your link is *not* the same as the object in question. Wikipedia's "Dunce Hat" has its edges identified differently, and the article points out that it is in fact contractible.